# Is the nuclear envelope present in G1 of interphase?

Tags: dna, cell-cycle

Is the nuclear envelope present in G1 of interphase of eukaryotic cell? If so how does a method like Calcium mediated transfection get DNA past the nuclear envelope?

Comment: That is a very good question. I have done calcium phosphate transfections on primary hepatocytes, so I know it works on non-dividing cells, but I don't think there's a clear answer yet. The calcium ions released from the particles may help trigger nuclear envelope disintigration and allow plasmid DNA to enter. I'll try and find and find links to a couple papers I've read about it.

Comment: Alright, Paper [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21774979) and [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17123600) by Dana Olton are about Calcium phosphate nanoparticle transfection and intracellular trafficking. Leaf Huang has several papers about lipid coated Calcium phosphate for DNA delivery in vivo, [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23647441), [2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24032396), and [3](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23964565). And [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24204256) is a paper about parvoviruses and how they enter the nucleus, which involves Ca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question about nuclear envelope in G1 phase, yes it exists. The nuclear envelope is reformed at the end of [Telophase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telophase) after the 2 copies of the DNA are pulled apart, but before the two daughter cells are separated by cytokinesis. We can see the new nuclear envelope in these images:
[image: reappearance of nucleus in telophase]

Image from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telophase)

[image: Nucleus present in cytokinesis]

Nuclei visible near end of cytokinesis, centrosome still visible. Image from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytokinesis).

As for how DNA gets into the nucleus without cellular division I don't have a good answer and I'm not sure anyone does right now. The nuclear envelope is a major barrier for non-viral gene delivery.